# Rotate Text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to draw a few strings in a custom view with swift. I have done the same thing on Android with Java, and here's the result:

[image: Android Sample]

With Swift, I get this graphic:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

extension NSString {
    func drawWithBasePoint(basePoint: CGPoint, andAngle angle: CGFloat, andAttributes attributes: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let textSize: CGSize = self.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(basePoint.x, basePoint.y)
        let r: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, t)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, r)
        self.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(textSize.width / 2, -textSize.height / 2), withAttributes: attributes)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformInvert(r))
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformInvert(t))
    }
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        elements = delegate!.getRotaryElements(self)
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)
        let sectorSize = 2 * π / CGFloat.init(elements.count)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        for i in 0...elements.count - 1 {
            let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:(i % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.redColor():primaryColor)]
            elements[i].drawWithBasePoint(center, andAngle: CGFloat(i) * sectorSize + (sectorSize / 2), andAttributes: attrs)
        }
    }
```

How can I produce the same thing in Swift? I am new to Swift (and iOS for that matter) and would appreciate any hint you can give me.

Comment: What does your `drawWithBasePint` method look like? it doesn't come from the iOS SDK.

Comment: @Fujia Sorry. I had forgotten to include it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below, and to see if it works.

```
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

extension NSString {
    func drawWithBasePoint(basePoint: CGPoint, andAngle angle: CGFloat, andAttributes attributes: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let radius: CGFloat = 100
        let textSize: CGSize = self.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(basePoint.x, basePoint.y)
        let r: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, t)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, r)
        self.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(radius-textSize.width/2, -textSize.height/2), withAttributes: attributes)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformInvert(r))
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformInvert(t))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5.0:

```
    extension String {
    func drawWithBasePoint(basePoint: CGPoint,
                           andAngle angle: CGFloat,
                           andAttributes attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]) {
        let textSize: CGSize = self.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: basePoint.x, y: basePoint.y)
        let r: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        context.concatenate(t)
        context.concatenate(r)
        self.draw(at: CGPoint(x: textSize.width / 2, y: -textSize.height / 2), withAttributes: attributes)
        context.concatenate(r.inverted())
        context.concatenate(t.inverted())
    }
}
```